# mySQL copy and paste row to end of same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql table called `users` that has a unique `id` column plus loads of other columns, too many to list.

Is it possible to duplicate a specific row data using `id` and add it to the end of the table with a new ID without having to list each column name?

Comment: No, this is not possible, at least not easily.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the id column is auto-incremented, you can do what you want by listing the columns as:

```
insert into t(. . .)  -- all but id
    select . . .   -- all but id
    from t
    where id = @id;
```

You can get the columns to list using `information_schema`:

```
select group_concat(column_name)
from information_schema.columns
where table_schema = @schema and table_name = @name and
      column_name <> 'id';
```

You can copy and paste the columns into the above query.  Or, you could even put the values in a variable, construct the SQL statement, and use `prepare`.